# Regular Expression Checking For Proper Extension Names

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am an issue with my javascript calling valid extensions invalid when they should pass. Ive used this regular expression in server side code and it worked fine for me. 
I verified that the value the reg expression is checking against is valid as well.

Am I declaring reg expression wrong maybe in the javascript?

```
 var ck_name = /^.+\.((gdf)|(GDF))$/;
 var chldValue = chld.value.substring(chld.value.length - 4, chld.value.length);
    alert(chldValue);

    if (!ck_name.test(chldValue)) {
        errors[errors.length] = "File is NOT a GDF file";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `^.+` is unnecessary and timewasting.

Second, your string is only four character long and what you are looking for... is a minimum of five characters long. Consequently they will never match.

Third, a regex is overkill.

Finally, your code should be:

```
if( chld.value.substr(chld.value.length-4).toLowerCase() != ".gdf")
    errors.push("File is NOT a GDF file");
```

Comment: +1 Only difference is that your allows for mixed case. Don't know why that would be undesirable.

Comment: Mind you, this is a moot point. I can rename any file to have a `.gdf` extension, regardless of whether it's a GDF file or not.

Comment: Ironically, the original code would have worked fine, if you hadn't then used substring to reduce what you were matching against. What's here though, is cleaner.